# How to get injected locals from $controller

Tags: angularjs

I created a controller through $controller and injected some values, and I expected that I could get it via $injector.get in the controller, but failed.

```
$controller(controllerFunc, {name: 'ron'})
var controllerFunc = function($injector){
    $injector.get('name'); // failed here
};
```

Could anyone fix this issue for me, thanks.

Ron

## update 1

Actually, the problem I am facing with is that I want to share a controller in two scenarios, one is in ui-bootstrap modal window and another one is in normal routes. See the following for more details:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('editUser', function($scope, $modalInstance) {
    // ...
})
```

For the controller named as 'editUser', it is ok when I use it in $modal.open, but it doesn't work for normal routes. So my original try is

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('editUser', function($scope, $injector) {
    var $modalInstance;

    // the following doesn't work for the scenario of $modal.open
    if ($injector.has('$modalInstance')) {
        $modalInstance = $injector.get('$modalInstance'); 
    }
})
```

Comment: $injector is undefined right ..?

Answer (score 2):

`$modalInstance` is only available to a controller used on the `$modal` opened for itself. It's more like a `resolved` dependency, like we see on `$route`s, for example.

To get it you need to **annotate** it on an `angular.controller()` declaration:

```
angular.controller('Users', ['$modalInstance', function (inst) {
    console.log(inst); // Will log the entire object of the current modalInstace
});
```

I've changed the function argument purposely because it doesn't matter its name when you annotate the dependencies. By the way, it's the correct way to declare the dependency injection to avoid minification renaming issues.

So, as you want to use the same controller to both situations, on `$route` and on a `$modal`, you need to be aware that the `$modalInstance` will be undefined on the `$route` controller use.

You have some guidelines:

1 - Handle the undefined code that will show up, during the use of the same code in several places;

2 - Develop the controller code using scoped functions under it, that receive as arguments the dependencies you'll need;

3 - Do not let specific code of a particular dependency be processed for all contexts;

However **1**: I suggest to you to build up a class that can deal with the common tasks between the contexts and inject it as a service on the specific controllers.

However **2**: Build up a separate function/class, that will be the controller for the contexts and create `new` instances of it, when you'll use them, `$inject`ing the dependencies for each situation:

```
function Controller () {
    /* Your dependencies */
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        deps = {};

    if (!!this.$inject && this.$inject.length) {
        this.$inject.map(function (item, index) {
            deps[item] = args[index];
        });
    }
    /* /Your dependencies */

    this.methodA = function methodA () {
        /* Common Code */
    };

    this.methodB = function methodB () {
        /* Common Code */
    };
}
```

On `$routeProvider` configuration:

```
$routeProvider.when('/users/:user', {
    controler: function () {
        var output = new Controller();

        ouput.$inject = ['depA', 'depB', 'depC'];

        return output;
    },
    controllerAs: 'users',
    template: '<div id="exampleTemplate" ng-bind="users.anyProperty"></div>"
});
```

On `$modal` call (even inside the same `Controller()`):

```
/* Other "Controller" function Code... */

    this.methodB = function methodB () {
        deps.$modal.open({
            controler: function () {
                var output = new Controller();

                ouput.$inject = ['depA', 'depB', '$modalInstance'];

                return output;
            },
            controllerAs: 'usersModal'
        });
    };

/* /Other "Controller" function Code... */
```

That applied, you'll be able to, for example, inside the `Controller()`, declare a function that use `$modalInstance`:

```
/* Other "Controller" function Code... */

    this.methodC = function methodC () {
        return deps.$modalInstance.$close();
    };

/* /Other "Controller" function Code... */
```

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: It works, smart solution. The only drawback is a bit tricky to maintain the code.

Comment: Indeed. Particularly I preffer to define the common methods that will work for both contexts, `$route` and `$modal` on a service, and let the controllers be one only for each.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. it will fail here: var output = new Controller(), because at this moment the arguments inside this function is empty.

Comment: Indeed, I've forgot these. Did you tried to put the arguments that you need  on the `new Controller($scope, ...)`? This is possible, check it out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: Even I can do new Controller($scope, ), I cannot make all these parameters ready here. Is it possible to trigger angular Ioc and let angular get these objects ready automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the concept. `myController` defines the constructor of the controller. Provider params, as the **$injector**, will be injected automatically, but the custom params as **param1**, **param2** and **$scope** must be provided to the constructor. With the `$injector` you can get any object/service, which are registered at startup - but not local params.

Hope this helps.

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .run(function($controller, $rootScope) {

    var myController = function($scope, $injector, param1, param2) {
      console.log(param1);
      console.log(param2);
      console.log($injector);
      console.log($injector.get('$http'));
    }

    var locals = {
      '$scope': $rootScope.$new(),
      'param1': 'value1',
      'param2': 'value2'
    };

    var ctrl = $controller(myController, locals);

  });
```

Comment: I understood what you try to express, but it doesn't solve my problem. see "update 1" what I just updated in my question.

Comment: `$modalInstance` is an instance and not a singleton. You have to create one manually and you can access it with the $injector. AfaIk `$injector` is only for registered services. - The solution to your problem is put the `$modalInstance` in a service and use the service to access it.